# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'LpAffineExpression' and 'int'

Tags: python, pulp

I'm very new to pulp and I'm trying to use it to find the best fit for the model that minimises the difference between the model data and the observed data. But I keep getting stuck with error messages that don't allow me to use ** in the objective function.

Here is an example of the code:

```
import pulp
import numpy as np

# Define the decision variables
m = pulp.LpVariable('m', lowBound=None)
b = pulp.LpVariable('b', lowBound=None)

# Define the problem as a minimization problem
problem = pulp.LpProblem('Minimize Squared Differences', pulp.LpMinimize)

# Define the objective function
objective = 0
x_values = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
y_values = [2.0, 5.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0]

for x, y in zip(x_values, y_values):
    y_model = m * x + b
    objective += (y_model - float(y))**2

problem += objective

# Solve the problem
status = problem.solve()

# Print the results
print('m =', m.value())
print('b =', b.value())
print('Objective value =', objective.value())
```

I have tried using:

```
(y_model - y)**2
```

,

```
(y_model - y)*(y_model - y)
```

and

```
np.power(y_model-y)
```

and none of the above worked.

I have tried updating pulp in command and I checked the version of my python which is 3.9.7. Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you using pulp for this? You seem to want to perform a linear regression? Linear programming and linear regression are two different techniques.

Comment: Hi Abdul Aziz Barkat, thanks for your reply. This is an example, I just want to know how I can use ** in the   objective function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are trying to include a non-linear operation in a linear program.  Squaring or multiplying a variable * variable is non-linear.  You *could* use a different framework and construct a non-linear program, but you give up a lot of the simplicity and guarantees of an LP.

If you want to stay with an LP, you should consider alternatives to “squared error”.  A common method that remains linear is to minimize the absolute error.  You can do this by introducing another variable as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108936/how-to-make-integer-optimization-with-absolute-values-in-python/64109078#64109078%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108936/how-to-make-integer-optimization-with-absolute-values-in-python/64109078#64109078) and minimize that.