# Optimization problem with Integer variables and a squared objective

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

The following code works:

```py
import cvxpy as cp

a = cp.Variable()
b = cp.Variable()
c = cp.Variable()
d = cp.Variable()

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.square(-2*a + 1.5*b + 3*c + 6.5*d - 2000))

constraints = [a >= 0, b>=0, c>=0, d>=0, a+b<=3000, c+d<=2000, a+c == 500, b+d == 2000]

cp.Problem(objective, constraints).solve()

print("optimal var", a.value, b.value,c.value, d.value)
```

However, if I use integral variables, e.g.,

```py
a = cp.Variable(integer=True)
```

this basic example will no longer work and results in the error

```
Either candidate conic solvers (%s) do not support the cvxpy.error.SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['SCIPY']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, NonNeg, Zero), or there are not enough constraints in the problem
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get around this? Or a better Python package to use?

Comment: instead of using a squared error, if it is acceptable to use absolute error in your model (assuming it is more complicated than the trivial example above) that can be made into a MILP and avoid the complication of an integer-based NLP

Comment: @AirSquid, excellent idea, I think that will work... thank you!

Comment: this may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108936/how-to-make-integer-optimization-with-absolute-values-or-sum-of-absolute-values/64109078#64109078

Comment: The error itself is due to the nonexistence of open-source solvers (available in cvxpy) for this problem. See [docs](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver). If you are in academia, you might obtain some commercial solver supported. Looking at the table again: scip should work (although quite different compared to commercials). It seems you need to take care at install-time such that the scip solver is available: [docs](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/#pip).

Comment: Use an MIQP solver. E.g., you can use demo versions of Gurobi or Cplex. Sometimes ECOS_BB can work (but I have not had much luck with this solver).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to express the problem in AMPL, and then use any non-linear solvers such as bonmin, ipopt (both open source) that gets shipped with AMPL. AMPL also has a rich python API as well where you formulate the problem in AMPL and then pass data from python data structures (rather than having a `.dat` file in native AMPL).
https://amplpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

AMPL now offers a full fledge community edition license and can be downloaded from https://ampl.com/start-free-now/
If you want to use AMPL with python, then follow the first link to install individual solvers. Its very easy to do that.

Below is the formulation in AMPL. I personally like AMPL for its expressiveness and its succinct syntax.

`squared_objective.mod`

```
var a >= 0 integer;
var b >= 0 integer;
var c >= 0 integer;
var d >= 0 integer;

subject to a_b_constraint:
    a + b <= 3000;

subject to c_d_constraint:
    c + d <= 2000;

subject to a_c_constraint:
    a + c = 500;

subject to b_d_constraint:
    b + d = 2000;

minimize obj_fn:
    (-2*a + 1.5*b + 3*c + 6.5*d - 2000) * (-2*a + 1.5*b + 3*c + 6.5*d - 2000);
```

Now, you can use any non-linear solver such as bonmin, ipopt, even cbc is also able to solve.

using gurobi `options solver gurobiasl;` results in:

```
ampl: options solver gurobiasl;
ampl: solve;
Gurobi 10.0.1: optimal solution; objective 0
2 simplex iterations
1 branch-and-cut nodes

ampl: display obj_fn;
obj_fn = 0

ampl: display a; display b; display c; display d;   
a = 500

b = 2000

c = 0

d = 0
```

Any other non-linear solver pointed above will work just fine

Now, using python API of AMPL:

```
from amplpy import AMPL

ampl = AMPL()
ampl.set_option("solver", "cbc")
# OR ampl.set_option("solver", "gurobiasl")
# OR ampl.set_option("solver", "ipopt")
# community edition of Gurobi gets shipped with AMPL !

ampl.read("../squared_objective.mod")

ampl.solve()

assert ampl.get_value("solve_result") == "solved"

# objective function value
ampl.getObjective("obj_fn").value()
# optimal value = 0

# decision variable values
ampl.getValue("a") # a = 500
ampl.getValue("b") # b = 2000
ampl.getValue("c") # c = 0
ampl.getValue("d") # d = 0
```

Use can easily use python data structures such as list, dictionaries and then pass data to your AMPL program

https://amplpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#load-the-data-using-pandas-objects
https://amplpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#load-the-data-using-lists-and-dictionaries